# Html template conversion to asp.net/razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

The template we are using has the structure set up like this.

```
<li><a href="dashboard.html"><span class="iconfa-laptop"></span>Dashboard</a></li>
```

Razor lets us use @Html helpers.

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
```

The  above adds an icon to the left of the link text.  Is there a way to duplicate this structure using Html helpers?

Or is the only way to type out the html manually?

Comment: I am guessing you can't do this? <li><span class="iconfa-laptop"></span>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>

Comment: @MikeHewitt sadly I cannot, I tried it and it distorted the icon and placed it far to the left.  So I'm guessing the css structure expects it in the above way.

Comment: @MikeHewitt The `<span>` must be *inside* the `<a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way using `Url.Action` instead of `Actionlink`

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><span class="iconfa-laptop"></span>Dashboard</a></li>
```

All you need is to generate the path, so this will do it. Otherwise you will have to create a helper extension for `ActionLink` to take an innerHTML content.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution, you could also accomplish what you want easily via CSS without needing to worry about extending functionality of the HtmlHelper.  Plus, it cuts down on your markup as well, e.g.

```
.iconfa-laptop {
   display:inline-block;
   padding-left: 18px;
   line-height:18px;
   background: url('your-image')  center left no-repeat;
}

<a class="iconfa-laptop" href="dashboard.html">Test Link</a>
```

Then, you can simply do the following:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new {@class = "iconfa-laptop"})</li>
```

[CSSPad Example](http://lukepeters.me/csspad/Jahcuj110)

Comment: I'm sure this method would work, but the template CSS file is extremely confusing `.iconfa-laptop:before{content:"\f109"}` I'm not even sure how this works.  There is no image called `f109` but it does point to some font awesome thing.

Comment: Thanks George that will help me understand better how that portion of this template does what it does.  I may even get brave enough to alter it so I can take full advantage of the Html helpers in razor.  Thanks for the extra time. :)